# Taking 100000 inputs in java Sorting program and it shows error in the output

Tags: java

i have taken 10 inputs and my program works perfectly but as i start taking large number of inputs like 100,1000 my programs does not work and get an error or generally it stops working.

So how can i solve it please give me solution.
Below is the code i have written:

```
 package PROGARMS;
 import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Radix1 {
public static void main(String[] args){
int i,j,k=0,x=10,m=0,n; 
Scanner k1=new Scanner(System.in);
Random r=new Random();
System.out.println("enter number of elements u want to sort");
n=k1.nextInt();
 int[] a=new int[n];
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    a[i]=r.nextInt(10000);
}

n=a.length;

System.out.println("Array before sorting");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    System.out.println(a[i]+" ");
System.out.println();



int[] b=new int[n];
int[] z=new int[n];

int max=a[0];
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
    if(max<a[i])
        max=a[i];

}

int length=0;
while(max!=0)
{
    length++;
    max=max/10;
}

//length=1;
System.out.println("length="+length);

    while(m<length){
        System.out.println("x="+x);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
     b[i]=a[i]%x;
}

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
    if(b[i]<b[j])
    {
        int key=b[i];
        b[i]=b[j];
        b[j]=key;      
      }
   }
}
for(int s=0;s<n;s++)
    System.out.println("s="+s+",b[s]="+b[s]);






  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
  {
    if(b[i]==a[j]%x)
        {
            if(k>=n)
            {
            System.out.println("k is greater,M="+m);
            k=0;
            }
        //ystem.out.println("k="+k+",j="+j);
        z[k]=a[j];


        a[j]=0;

        k++;
        }
        }


 }


 for(int s=0;s<n;s++)
a[s]=z[s];

//for(int s=0;s<n;s++)
//System.out.println("s="+s+",a[s]="+a[s]);



m++;
x=x*10;

k=0;
System.out.println();
}

    System.out.println("After sorting Final result");
    for(int s=0;s<n;s++)
        System.out.println("s="+s+",a[s]="+a[s]);
 }
  }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: There's really no way to answer this.  What is your program trying to do, what is the code you've written, what error are you seeing when it fails?

Comment: it is a program for radix sort

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it: In your main sort loop, when you're moving the values from `a` across to `z`, you remove them from `a` after you're done.  That's fine, except you 'remove' them by setting them to 0:

```
a[j]=0;
```

Thing is, 0 is a valid value, so if your loop is looking for values with a 0 in this place, this does not remove it from consideration.  This shows up as `k` overrunning the array, which triggers the `k is greater,M=` message, but this is swallowed and the program continues.

You can fix this by setting `a[j]` to a value it couldn't possibly be:

```
a[j]=-1;
```

This then can't be double-counted, and the bug disappears.

I've written this change and changed the guard condition to throw an exception below.  I've also added some comments for readability, and some changes to the logging which made it more readable for me (although your taste may vary).

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RadixSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, j, k = 0, x = 10, m = 0, n;
        Random r = new Random();
        Scanner k1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of elements you want to sort");
        n = k1.nextInt();


        // Choose random numbers to sort
        int[] a = new int[n];
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = r.nextInt(10000);
        }

        // Print initial array
        System.out.println("Array before sorting");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();

        // Find the largest value
        int max = a[0];
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            if (max < a[i])
                max = a[i];

        }

        // Find the (decimal) length of the longest value
        int length = 0;
        while (max != 0) {
            length++;
            max = max / 10;
        }
        System.out.println("length=" + length);

        // Main sort loop
        int[] b = new int[n];
        int[] z = new int[n];
        while (m < length) {
            // Place being sorted
            System.out.println("x=" + x);
            // `b` is a copy of `a` including only the digit to be sorted in this pass
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                b[i] = a[i] % x;
            }

            // Bubble sort `b`
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    if (b[i] < b[j]) {
                        int key = b[i];
                        b[i] = b[j];
                        b[j] = key;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Print out the sorted `b` array
            for (int s = 0; s < n; s++)
                System.out.print(b[s]+",");
            System.out.println();

            // Apply the sort from `b` to `a`.
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    // If the ith entry in `a` has the same digit as `b`, move it across 
                    if (b[i] == a[j] % x) {
                        // XXX: Some kind of loop guard?  This indicates an error, and should exit.
                        if (k >= n) {
                          throw new IllegalStateException("k is greater than n, when M=" + m);
                        }
                        // Move the jth value out of `a` into a temporary buffer `z`.
                        z[k] = a[j];

                        // XXX: Problem is, '0' is a valid value.
                        a[j] = -1;

                        k++;
                    }
                }

            }

            // Transcribe the sorted array back into `a`
            for (int s = 0; s < n; s++)
                a[s] = z[s];

            // Move on to the next digit.
            m++;
            x = x * 10;
            k = 0;
        }

        // Print the final result
        System.out.println("After sorting Final result");
        for (int s = 0; s < n; s++)
            System.out.print(a[s]+",");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```